# Next.js useFileSystemPublicRoutes:false doesn't work with rewrites use slug

Tags: javascript, next.js

I added rewrites for my custom url pages. And it worked. But after when i added useFileSystemPublicRoutes: false, my nested pages have started not work. Non-slug pages open. Example "/". But when i use slug, it doesnt work and get 404. Actually when i run "npm run dev" it works but when i run npm run build and npm start i get 404.

Also I opened issue on github: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/27590

pages/reset-password/[resetId].js

```
module.exports = {
  useFileSystemPublicRoutes: false,
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/', -> it works
        destination: '/' 
      },
      {
        source: "/sifre-sifirla/:slug*", -> get 404
        destination: "/reset-password/:slug*", 
      },
   ];
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using a [custom server](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server) to do the routing instead?

Comment: I am using only rewrites for routing. @juliomalves